# Updated branch from master on git but new release is missing

Tags: git, github, branch, release

I have forked a branch to my github from my collaborators github.
Now we made a new release and I merged them so my branch is up to date with the master branch from my collaborator and I can see the new commits and files on my branch, however, the new release is not there.

Does anyone have any idea what to do in this case?

Thank you!

Comment: Your description is quite unclear. Could you join some branch schema? Maybe just the output of `git log --all --oneline --graph --decorate -30` ?

Comment: thank you @RomainValeri, problem already solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With releases you normally mean tags. Based on how you sync your fork with the original repository, you need to `git push --tags` in the end. Have a look before that, if the tags are already part of your fork (normally branch `origin`) by `git tag`.